# From DB2 to Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, db2, locking

We are currently building an application based on an Oracle DB. With this application we want to replace an existing application that works with DB2 databases.
Some programs are realized by means of "for update of" statetments. These work fine when accessing DB2. However, if the programs access the oracle, I get the following error message:

> ORA-02014: can not select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP
>   BY, etc.

Is there a way to solve this problem without handling the programs? Is there a property that allows this? we use ojdbc8 drivers on our linux server for access

---

Edit from 21.01.2020

here is an example from the query that does not work when accessing the oracle DB

```
SELECT DBU.VIEW3.COL7, DBU.VIEW3.COL2, DBU.VIEW3.COL3, DBU.VIEW3.COL4, DBU.VIEW3.COL5, DBU.VIEW3.COL6, DBU.VIEW1.*  
FROM (
   DBU.VIEW1 LEFT JOIN DBU.VIEW2 
        ON (DBU.VIEW1.COL1=DBU.VIEW2.COL1) 
       AND (DBU.VIEW1.COL2=DBU.VIEW2.COL2) 
       AND (DBU.VIEW1.COL3=DBU.VIEW2.COL3)
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN DBU.VIEW3 ON DBU.VIEW3.COL7=DBU.VIEW2.COL7 
WHERE DBU.VIEW1.COL2='VALUE1' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL3='VALUE2' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL1='VALUE3' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL4='VALUE4' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL5='VALUE5' 
FOR UPDATE OF COL6
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code changes are likely required, but your question does not have any useful information to give specific advice.

Comment: The error message seems to make sense. Show us the trouble select.

Comment: FOR UPDATE issues locks on specific rows in the table. It sounds like your queries do not allow Oracle to determine which rows it needs to lock. How this works in DB2 I don't know, but you will have to re-write the queries for Oracle. Sorry.

Comment: If you want to ask "How can I fix my code that has this error?" then you need to [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with a minimal example of the source code you are trying to run. If you are asking "What does this error mean?" then its self explanatory - you can't use `FOR UPDATE` in a view where the query can't get a reference back to rows to lock them (i.e. when you've aggregated the rows).

Comment: here is an example:  
  
  SELECT DBU.VIEW3.COL7, DBU.VIEW3.COL2, DBU.VIEW3.COL3, DBU.VIEW3.COL4, DBU.VIEW3.COL5, DBU.VIEW3.COL6, DBU.VIEW1.*  
FROM (
   DBU.VIEW1 LEFT JOIN DBU.VIEW2 
        ON (DBU.VIEW1.COL1=DBU.VIEW2.COL1) 
       AND (DBU.VIEW1.COL2=DBU.VIEW2.COL2) 
       AND (DBU.VIEW1.COL3=DBU.VIEW2.COL3)
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN DBU.VIEW3 ON DBU.VIEW3.COL7=DBU.VIEW2.COL7 
WHERE DBU.VIEW1.COL2='VALUE1' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL3='VALUE2' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL1='VALUE3' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL4='VALUE4' 
  AND DBU.VIEW1.COL5='VALUE5' 
FOR UPDATE OF COL6

Answer (score 1):

Oracle alows to update tables by views, colled 'updatable views'. Substantailly, the view should satisfy a few conditions to enable update operations, there should be:
- no DISTINCT clause in the view definition,
- no GROUP BY operations in the view definition.

Your error code point to such no updatable view probably.

Comment: The question is specifically about ORA-02014, which relates to a query modified with a FOR UPDATE clause. In this context the *"view"* mentioned in the error message might well be an inline view (aka derived table). For instance, we would get this error if the query has an inline view to apply a filter using ROWNUM. In short, your answer is not wrong but it's not complete enough to be truly helpful.